# Xcode 4 new functions - which one do you use, and which one you don't?

Tags: xcode4

With the new XCode 4, some new functions have been introduced.

Which of these new functions do **YOU** often use ?

**Which one don't you use and why ?** For those one, can you tell what you do that is for you greater than using the new provided functions, and why is this greater ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great [review by Martin Pilkington](http://pilky.me/view/15) that I wholeheartedly agree with (including the part about the documentation changes).

Comment: +1 for the review. I've been trying out the recently released 1.0 (free) Ingredients app - http://fileability.net/ingredients/

Comment: Yes, Ingredients is great! Now if I could just have cmd+opt+doubleclicking back…